# How can I call a Oracle stored function returning BOOLEAN value?

Tags: vb.net, oracle, stored-functions

I have created a test package containing a single function that takes no input parameters and returns a BOOLEAN. The function body consists of a single `RETURN TRUE` statement for the sake of simplifying this question.

In VB.Net, I am successfully calling the function, however, I am always getting an exception `PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type`. 
In my vb code, I create a parameter and set its direction to `ReturnValue` and its `DbType` to `Int16` to store the boolean result (since there is no native boolean type in the `DbType` structure). That did not work, so I tried `Double` then `Decimal` then `Long` and `Varchar2` but they all caused the same exception.

What am I doing wrong here?

## *package specifications*

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE TEST_PKG AS 
   FUNCTION GET_TEST_VAL RETURN BOOLEAN;
END TEST_PKG;
```

,

## *package body*

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY TEST_PKG AS
   FUNCTION GET_TEST_VAL RETURN BOOLEAN IS
   BEGIN
     RETURN TRUE;
   END GET_TEST_VAL;
END TEST_PKG;
```

,

## *vb.net code*

```
Dim con As New OracleConnection("Data Source=test_db;user id=scott;password=123456")
Dim cmd As OracleCommand = con.CreateCommand()
cmd.CommandText = "TEST_PKG.GET_TEST_VAL"

Dim ret_val As New OracleParameter
ret_val.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue
ret_val.DbType = OracleDbType.Int16 '//<-- I tried varchar2, decimal, long, double'
cmd.Parameters.Add(ret_val)
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()  '//<-- This raises an Exception (PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type)'

Console.WriteLine("Return Value = " & ret_val.Value.ToString)

con.Close()
```

Comment: And what data provider do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no support of PL\SQL `BOOLEAN` type in some data providers (i don't know which one you use). The usual workaround is to use `NUMBER` instead in your code. If you have to use third party rutines and you can't alter them you should wrap your calls in anonymous block like this:

```
BEGIN
    :ret := CASE third_party_proc_call WHEN true THEN 1 ELSE 0 END;
END;
```